# Intersection Between a Line and a Cone

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a point of origin ($x_e,y_e,z_e$) and a unit direction vector in the direction of the line ($\hat s$). I also have a conical surface that is described in vector form. I'm unsure of how to find the point of intersection between the conical surface and a line along the direction vector with these knowns.

Depiction of the surface:

[image]

Comment: The equation of the surface of cone is $z = \frac{h}{r_1 - r_2} [r_1 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}]$. The equation of the line is $(x_e, y_e, z_e) + \hat s \ t$. You can find the value of $t$ and hence the point where the line intersects the surface of the cone.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{e}$ be the emission point, $\hat{s}$ its unit vector, so we can parametrise the emitted ray as a vector-valued function
$$\vec{p}(d) = \vec{e} + d \hat{s} \tag{1}\label{G1}$$
where $d \ge 0$ is the distance from the emission point.

Let the base of the circular cone be at origin, with its radius there $r_0$. Let $\hat{a}$ be the cone unit axis vector, so that its apex is at $H\hat{a}$.

We only have a partial cone with height $h$, where the radius is $r_1 \lt r_0$, but that just means that if we need it, we can calculate $H$ trivially via
$$H = \frac{h r_0}{r_0 - r_1}$$
At distance $z$ from the plane of the cone base (i.e., measured along the cone axis), the radius $r$ of the cone is
$$r(z) = \frac{r_1 z + r_0 (h - z)}{h} = r_0 + \frac{r_1 - r_0}{h} z \tag{2a}\label{G2a}$$
Because in the valid range $0 \le z \le h$ this is positive, we can use it squared:
$$r^2(z) = \frac{\bigl( r_1 z + r_0 ( h - z ) \bigr)^2}{h^2} = \left( r_0 + \frac{r_1 - r_0}{h} z \right)^2 \tag{2b}\label{G2b}$$
For simplicity, let's use
$$r^2(z) = (R_1 z + R_0)^2 \tag{2c}\label{G2c}$$
where $R_1$ and $R_0$ are constants specific to this cone,
$$\begin{aligned}
R_0 &= r_0 \\
R_1 &= \frac{r_1 - r_0}{h} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2d}\label{G2d}$$

Point $\vec{p}$ is at distance $\vec{p} \cdot \hat{a}$ from the plane of the cone base.  Its distance from the cone axis is then $\left\lVert\vec{p} - \hat{a} (\vec{p} \cdot \hat{a})\right\rVert$.

So, ray $\vec{p}(d)$ intersects this cone, if
$$\begin{aligned}
z &= \vec{p}(d) \cdot \hat{a} \\
0 \le z &\le h \\
\end{aligned} \tag{A}\label{GA}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\lVert \vec{p}(d) - z \hat{a} \right\rVert^2 &= r^2(z) \\
\end{aligned} \tag{B}\label{GB}$$
To find the intersection, we need to solve for $d$, and verify that the corresponding $z$ fulfills $0 \le z \le h$.

Combining $\eqref{G1}$ and $\eqref{GA}$ we get
$$z = d \left(\vec{s} \cdot \hat{a} \right) + \vec{e} \cdot \hat{a}$$
If we define constants
$$\begin{aligned}
Z_1 &= \vec{s} \cdot \hat{a} \\
Z_0 &= \vec{e} \cdot \hat{a} \\
\end{aligned}$$
for this particular ray, we can write
$$z = Z_1 d + Z_0$$
so we can write $\vec{p}(d) - z \hat{a}$ as
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{p}(d) - z \hat{a} &= \vec{e} + d \hat{s} - (Z_1 d + Z_0) \hat{a} \\
~ &= d (\hat{s} - Z_1 \hat{a}) + \vec{e} - Z_0 \hat{a} \\
~ &= d \vec{P} + \vec{Q} \\
\vec{P} &= \hat{s} - Z_1 \hat{a} = \left[ \begin{matrix} P_x \\ P_y \\ P_z \end{matrix} \right] \\
\vec{Q} &= \vec{e} - Z_0 \hat{a} = \left[ \begin{matrix} Q_x \\ Q_y \\ Q_z \end{matrix} \right] \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ are temporary vectors for this ray and cone.  Substituting these into $\eqref{GB}$ we get
$$(P_x d + Q_x)^2 + (P_y d + Q_y)^2 + (P_z d + Q_z)^2 = (R_1 Z_1 d + R_1 Z_0 + R_0)^2$$
which is a simple quadratic equation in $d$, and can be written as
$$B_2 d^2 - 2 B_1 d + B_0 = 0 \tag{C}\label{GC}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
B_2 &= P_x^2 + P_y^2 + P_z^2 - R_1^2 Z_1^2 \\
B_1 &= Z_1 R_1 (R_1 Z_0 + R_0) - P_x Q_x - P_y Q_y - P_z Q_z \\
B_0 &= Q_x^2 + Q_y^2 + Q_z^2 - (R_1 Z_0 + R_0)^2 \\
\end{aligned}$$

To solve, first find $d$:

- If $B_2 = 0$ and $B_1 \ne 0$, $$d = \frac{B_0}{2 B_1}$$

  Otherwise,
- If $B_1^2 \ge B_0 B_2$, $$d = \frac{B_1}{B_2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ B_1^2 - B_0 B_2 }}{B_2}$$

  Otherwise, there is no intersection.

If you find one or two candidate $d$, verify that
$$d \ge 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad 0 \le Z_1 d + Z_0 \le h$$
as negative $d$ indicate intersections occurring in the opposite direction, and $Z_1 d + Z_0$ corresponds to the distance from the cone base along the cone axis where the intersection occurs.

If you have two intersections, the emission point had to be outside the cone, as it intersects the cone twice.  If you find a valid $d$, then the intersection point is obviously $\vec{p}(d) = \vec{e} + d \vec{s}$.