# Find the A and B, as intersection points of line $r$ and cone $C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I am trying to figure out this question.

> Find the $A$ and $B$, as intersection points of line $r$ and cone $C$.
> $$
> r: 
> \eqalign{\cases{
> x &= 3t+6 \\ 
> y &= 4t+8 \\ 
> z &= 1
> }} \text{and}\space\space C:  x^2+y^2-25z^2=0
> $$

I managed to find the vector $v$ and emission point $A$:
$$
t=\frac{x-6}{3},\space\space t=\frac{y-8}{4},\space\space t=1\\
 v=(3,4,1) \text{ and } A=(-6,-8,1)
$$

But what are the next steps to find the other point $B$ ?

Comment: Why don't you just plug in $x,y,z$ from $r$ into the equation of the cone? You should get a quadratic in $t$, which should have two solutions. Also note that $\hat v$ is not correct. The last component is $0$. And you should not use $\vec A$ notation, when you have $A$ for a point of intersection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I based in this answer to write https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4085234/982430. I will edit tha question.

Comment: Are you certain of those conditions. The equation given for the cone actually represents a paraboloid of revolution.

Comment: That was my first thought. But it seems to be the Equation for a Circuloid (https://pt.scribd.com/document/387785525/GEOMETRIATAREA1)

Comment: @Luiz Vaz: The link you provided has a right circular cone labeled "circuloide," which I gather is its Spanish, or perhaps Portuguese, name. However, the equation you give above is not in the same form. The $z$ term would have to be degree two.

Comment: @Pope, yes it's Spanish.  My fault, $z$ is really $z^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the equation makes sense to me now. Substitute the components into the cone equation. That will give you a quadratic equation in $t$.

$x^2+y^2-25z^2=0\\
(3t+6)^2+(4t+8)^2-25(1)^2=0\\
25t^2+100t+75=0\\t^2+4t+3=0\\(t+3)(t+1)=0\\t=-3\space\space\text{or}\space\space t=-1$

$\text{Let}\space t=-3.\\x=3(-3)+6=-3\\y=4(-3)+8=-4\\z=1\\A(-3, -4, 1)$

$\text{Let}\space t=-1.\\x=3(-1)+6=3\\y=4(-1)+8=4\\z=1\\B(3, 4, 1)$

Comment: Thanks @Pope, this all make sense now!